# How to turn on/off the SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS view in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have one folder that contains multiple sub folders, and each of them is one git repository. Sometimes I can see this **SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS** view showing up and it's super helpful, but sometimes it doesn't show up. I would like to know if there is a switch on the vscode UI to turn on or off this view. (Maybe it's a plug in that I accidentally installed?)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It most likely only shows up when you are in the directory with the git repos. Any higher and only one repo will be available.

Comment: What extensions do you have?

Comment: I got some c++ and python helpers, nothing related to git. And I think you are right, as long as I open the files in the sub-folders, this window will show up automatically, no button or menu to turn it on/off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 1.17 released today (at least for me).  For info about that panel see [source control providers](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_source-control).  I don't see a toggle for that panel - I assume you always get it if you have multiple SC Providers and open up the source control icon <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! So this is a fairly new feature! When I google about it, it only shows the discussions about adding it on github.

Answer (score 9):

Version `1.31.1` has a config parameter to always show the source control providers:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to access settings
- Search for SCM
- Check the "Scm: Always Show Providers" option

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> but sometimes it doesn't show up

Starting  with 1.47 (June 2020), it does not show up at all, as it used to.
There is a [new "single-unified view"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_single-view):
(the old view might come back in 1.49, Sept. 2020, see at the end)

> The Source Control view has been consolidated into a single view:
>
> [image: Source Control with a single view]
>
> All repositories are rendered in a single view, so you can get a better overview of the entire workspace status.
> Additionally, the Source Control view can now be moved to the panel and other views can be moved to the Source Control view container

This... has not been appreciated. See [issue 102118](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102118):

> In the old system, if I had 4-5 repos showing, the one or two with active changes would show up clearly at the bottom.
> Now it's very muddled, and sort by status simply puts the repos with changes at the top.

> Here is the old view. List of changed files only show up when a repo is clicked. They are clear and distinct, separated from all the list of repos and everything else at the bottom.

[image: Screen Shot 2020-07-11 at 11 31 53 AM]

The new single source view. One has to hunt for the changes amidst a list of other repos. It is cluttered, hard to parse, and requires hunting to find what you want. The old view was much easier to follow and use.

[image: Screen Shot 2020-07-11 at 11 33 49 AM]

---

[issue 104151](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104151) proposes to bring back the old view

Example:

> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22350/89913517-19d34200-dbf4-11ea-8890-4cc4cc6a9fe1.gif]
>
> - The **`Source Control Repositories`** view is now back.
>   (It used to be called `Source Control Providers`).
>   It lets you control visibility of multiple repos in the Source Control view.
> - The setting `scm.repositories.visible` is now back
>   (It used to be called `scm.providers.visible`).
> - I've sprinkled visibility actions both in the context menu of the Source Control view as well as the ... menu, to make it easier to control the visibility without using the `Source Control Repositories` view.